# Reverse an array of integers without using Swift's object properties/methods

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm

At a last iOS Developer job interview I got a task that I didn't quite know how to do properly.

**Task:**
Reverse an array of integers in place.

**Inputs:** `arr` (the array), and `n` - which is the number of elements in `arr`

Allocate as little memory as possible, and **don't use Swift's object properties** (so basically **anything you access with a dot notation** e.g `.reverse()`, `.insert(at:` etc. **is not allowed**)

Comment: Hint: what will be the new index for an element that was located at index `0`? What will be the index for an element located at index `n`? index `1`?

Comment: Show the code you already tried.

Comment: Hint 2: you can swap the values of two variables `a` and `b` using tuple assignment: `(a, b) = (b, a)`.

Comment: minimal code: `arr.reduce([]) { [$1] + $0 }`

Comment: @MojtabaHosseini reduce is not in place

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### With tuples

```
func reverse(array: inout [Int], count: Int) {
    if count < 2 { return }
    var first = 0
    var last = count - 1
    while first < last {
        (array[first], array[last]) = (array[last], array[first])
        first += 1
        last -= 1
    }
}
```

### Without tuples

```
func reverse(array: inout [Int], count: Int) {
    func swapAt(_ firstIndex: Int, _ secondIndex: Int) {
        let firstValue = array[firstIndex]
        array[firstIndex] = array[secondIndex]
        array[secondIndex] = firstValue
    }

    if count < 2 { return }
    var first = 0
    var last = count - 1
    while first < last {
        swapAt(first, last)
        first += 1
        last -= 1
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice catch. I edited the code.